# Automatically cut plane by alpha channel

Tags: image

I have a png logo I have imported using the import images as planes addon. This means that when I enter rendered view, the plane is transparent in the places where opacity is 0. Can I take this information and cut the plane by the alpha channel? I know I can do this same thing manually with the knife tool but I am wondering if there is a faster way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173458/92768

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74332/carve-alpha-channel-from-plane?rq=1